# What assumptions would I have to make to rigorously prove power equals force dotted with velocity, $P=\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{v}$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, velocity, power

$\newcommand{\F}{\mathbf{F}}$$\newcommand{\r}{\mathbf{r}}$$\newcommand{\v}{\mathbf{v}}$$\newcommand{\d}[2]{ \frac{ d #1 }{ d #2 }}$ There’s a well-known known formula for the power $P$ exerted on a point mass $P=\F\cdot\v$ where $\F$ is the force doing the work and $\v$ is the velocity with which the point mass moves. The proof my instructor provided back in the day goes as follows:

$$\begin{align}
W &= \int\F\cdot d\r \\
W &= \int\F\cdot\d{\r}{t}\,dt \tag{a}\\
\d Wt &= \frac{d}{dt}\int \F\cdot\d{\r}{t}\,dt \tag{b} \\
P &= \frac{d}{dt}\int\F\cdot\v\,dt \tag{c}\\
P &= \F\cdot\v \tag{R}\\
\end{align}$$

There are a few reasons why I find this proof in general less than satisfactory:

- It makes no reference to limits of integration
- It does not appear to recognize that $\F$ can vary with $t$ as well as $\r$
- If does not appear to recognize that $\r$ varies with $t$
- step $\rm{(a)}$ might be making use of a possibly erroneous “differentials cancel” argument

---

In an attempt to rigorously derive $\rm{(R)}$, I have carefully defined the following:

- The interval under consideration ranges from $t=a$ to $t=b$
- $\r_t(t)$ maps a scalar time to the three-dimensional position vector of the point mass at that time
- $s_t(\tau)$ maps a scalar time to the scalar distance travelled by the point mass from $t=a$ to $t=\tau$ defined by $s_t(\tau)=\int_{a}^{\tau}\lvert\v_t(t)\rvert\,dt$
- $\F_\r(t,\r(t))$ maps a scalar time and the three-dimensional position vector of the point mass that corresponds to that time to the three-dimensional vector of the working force
- $\F_s(t,s(t))$ maps a scalar time and the scalar distance travelled by the point mass to the three-dimensional vector of the working force
- $F_s(t,s(t))$ maps a scalar time and the scalar distance travelled by the point mass to the scalar magnitude of the working force defined by $F_s(t,s(t))=\lvert\F_s(t,s(t))\rvert$

Assume a more precise definition of work:

$$W_t(a,b)=\int_{\r_t(a)}^{\r_t(b)} \F_\r(t,\r(t))\cdot d(\r_t(t))$$

I’ve made several attempts at this derivation using various methods (which I will not verbosely reproduce here), including:

- Leibniz integral rule
- Jacobian determinant
- Change or variables or $u$-substitution

but to no avail.

---

Are there any underlying assumptions in saying $P=\F\cdot\v$ that would allow one to derive the equation?

What method could one use to derive $P=\F\cdot\v$?[[

Comment: In what way do you think this approach ignores time-dependent forces? How would the basic approach change if F did depend on time? I don't see where except in that step where you don't like using the total differential.

Comment: @levitopher Maybe “does not explicitly express” is better than “ignores”

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus?wprov=sfla1

Comment: per khnzhou's answer below, the only real assumption made is that each component of ${\vec r}$ is a piecewise invertible function of $t$.  Then, the whole thing is just a change of variables from $r$ to $t$.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a rigorous derivation. The energy is $mv^2/2$, and power is the rate of change of energy, so 
$$\renewcommand{\v}[1]{\mathbf{#1}} P = \frac{d}{dt} \frac{m \v{v} \cdot \v{v}}{2} = m \v{a} \cdot \v{v} = \v{F} \cdot \v{v}.$$
That's it.

---

Now let's look at your derivation. The first step
$$W = \int \v{F}(\v{r}) \cdot d\v{r} = \int \v{F}(t) \cdot \frac{d\v{r}}{dt} dt$$
is valid, as this is just the chain rule. (Just because it *looks* like "canceling the differentials" doesn't mean it's wrong! Canceling differentials is completely fine as long as you know what you're doing.) Now rename $t$ to $\tau$ because the name of the integration variable doesn't matter. The next step is
$$\frac{dW}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt} \int \v{F}(\tau) \cdot \frac{d\v{r}}{d\tau} d\tau$$
and this is nonsensical because there is no dependence on $t$ to differentiate.

Instead, we should explicitly write integration bounds $t_i$ and $t_f$ where $W(t_i, t_f)$ is the work done from time $t_i$ to time $t_f$. Then 
$$\frac{dW}{dt_f} = \frac{d}{dt_f} \int_{t_i}^{t_f} \v{F}(\tau) \cdot \frac{d\v{r}}{d\tau} d\tau = \v{F}(t_f) \cdot \v{v}(t_f)$$
where we used the fundamental theorem of calculus. Now the left-hand side is equal to the power at time $t_f$, so
$$P(t_f) = \v{F}(t_f) \cdot \v{v}(t_f)$$
which is what we wanted.