# Distance-velocity relation for a body accelerated with constant power

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, kinematics, work, power

A body of mass $m$ starting from rest from the origin ($x(0)=0$ and $v(0)=0$ at $t=0$) moves along the x-axis under the influence of a force $F$ that exerts a constant power $P$.

**Question:** How to find the relation between velocity $v(t)$ and the distance moved by the body $x(t)$?

---

**My understanding:** I approached the problem in this manner.
Since $P$ is constant over time and $P=F\cdot v$ (see e.g. [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/346259/226902) or [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/364002/226902)), we have that

$$dP/dt=0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad   d(F\cdot v)/dt=0$$

or, equivalently,  $(dF/dt)\cdot v+F\cdot(dv/dt)=0$.
This means that $v \cdot dF = -F \cdot dv$. Alternatively, since we want to find a distance-velocity expression, we may use the derivative of [velocity with respect to position](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/297718/226902).

---

**Can one find the relation between velocity $v(t)$ and $x(t)$ and is it possible to do this without solving the trajectory $x(t)$?**

Comment: Dear Arghya Debm, I took the freedom to edit your question to make it clearer (math notation and an informative non-generic title). Please, try to follow the same use of math notation and give an informative title next time.

Comment: You could use the work-energy theorem, if you just want the velocity versus time. You don't need that derivation.

Comment: $P = m (dv/dt) v = m (dv/dx) (dx/dt) v = m (dv/dx) v^2.$  Integrate to solve for a direct relationship between $v$ and $x$.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/712186/392

Answer (score 1):

Power is defined as $P = F\,v$ and since $a = \frac{F}{m}$ which means that acceleration as a function of speed is

$$a = \frac{P}{m v}$$

To integrate the above to get time and distance as a function of speed you can use the following differential relationships

$$ \begin{aligned}
  {\rm d}t & = \frac{1}{a(v)} {\rm d}v & {\rm d}x & = \frac{v}{a(v)} {\rm d}v \\
 t(v) & = \int_0^v \frac{m v}{P} {\rm d}v & x(v) & = \int_0^v \frac{m v^2}{P} {\rm d}v \\
 t(v) & = \frac{m v^2}{2 P} & x(v) & = \frac{m v^3}{3 P}
\end{aligned} $$

The last equation can be found by the energy balance $P\, t = \tfrac{1}{2} m v^2$. Also combine the last two equations to get

$$\begin{aligned}
  v(t) & = \sqrt{ \frac{2 P t}{m} } & x(t) & = \sqrt{ \frac{8 P t^3}{9 m} }
\end{aligned}$$

---

To prove the differential relationships, consider ${\rm d}v = a(v) {\rm d} t$, and ${\rm d}t = \tfrac{1}{v} {\rm d}x = \tfrac{1}{a} {\rm d}v$.

Comment: +1 A particular behaviour: it is easy to check that the "average velocity" is always 2/3 of the "final velocity", $x(t)/t=2v(t)/3$.